# Producer/Consumer with some limitations

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

The code realizes producer/consumer problem with multiple producers and consumers. Have this code any potential deadlock or races?

```
//RandomDataProvider.cs

namespace MyNamespace.Core
{
    using System;

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides randomly generated data.
    /// </summary>
    public class RandomDataProvider
    {
        #region constuction

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes new instance of the <see cref="RandomDataProvider"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="maxSleepInterval"></param>
        public RandomDataProvider(int maxSleepInterval)
        {
            _maxSleepInterval = maxSleepInterval;
        }

        #endregion // constuction

        #region implementation

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the random sleeping interval.
        /// </summary>
        public int GetSleepInterval()
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                return _random.Next(_maxSleepInterval);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the random value.
        /// </summary>
        public int GetRandomValue()
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                return _random.Next(1, 100);
            }
        }

        #endregion // implementation

        #region representation

        private readonly Random _random = new Random();
        private readonly object _locker = new object();
        private readonly int _maxSleepInterval;

        #endregion // representation
    }
}

//Producer.cs

namespace MyNamespace.Core
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reprecents <see cref="Producer"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class Producer : RandomDataProvider
    {

        #region construction

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the new instance of <see cref="Producer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="queue">Queue to which producers put items.</param>
        /// <param name="maxSleepInterval">The maximum sleep interval.</param>
        public Producer(Queue<int> queue, int maxSleepInterval)
            : base(maxSleepInterval)
        {
            _queue = queue;
        }

        #endregion // construction

        #region implementation

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts produce items and put to queue.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token">Cancellation token.</param>
        public void StartProduce(CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // If canceled stop producing.
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(GetSleepInterval());
                int item = GetRandomValue();

                lock (_queue)
                {
                    if (_isReachedMax)
                    {
                        // if producer reached max items, block and wait until count decreases 80.
                        while (_queue.Count > 80)
                        {
                            Monitor.Wait(_queue);
                        }

                        // now we can release thread
                        _isReachedMax = false;
                    }

                    _queue.Enqueue(item);

                    if (_queue.Count == 1)
                    {
                        // Pulse comsumres which waits on empty queue
                        Monitor.Pulse(_queue);
                    }
                    else if (_queue.Count >= 100)
                    {
                        // Set reached max count flag.
                        _isReachedMax = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion // implementation


        #region representation

        private readonly Queue<int> _queue;
        private bool _isReachedMax;

        #endregion // representation

    }
}

//Consumer.cs

namespace MyNamespace.Core
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reprecents <see cref="Consumer"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class Consumer : RandomDataProvider, IDisposable
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the new instance of <see cref="Consumer"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="queue">The queue from which consumes items.</param>
        /// <param name="maxSleepInterval">The maximum sleep interval.</param>
        public Consumer(Queue<int> queue, int maxSleepInterval)
            :base(maxSleepInterval)
        {
            _queue = queue;
        }


        #region implementation

        #region Implementation of IDisposable

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the current instance.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            StreamWriter.Close();
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts consume items from queue.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="token">Cancellation token.</param>
        public void StartConsume(CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(GetSleepInterval());

                int item;

                lock (_queue)
                {
                    // If no item in queue after cancel, return.
                    if (_queue.Count == 0 && token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Wait when queue empty.
                    while (_queue.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(_queue);
                    }

                    item = _queue.Dequeue();

                    // if count decreases and reaches 80, then inform produsers which wait.
                    if (_queue.Count <= 80)
                    {
                        Monitor.PulseAll(_queue);
                    }
                }

                WriteToStream(item);
            }
        }

        #endregion // implementation

        #region operations

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes items to the stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item">Item to write.</param>
        private void WriteToStream(int item)
        {
            lock (StreamWriter)
            {
                StreamWriter.Write("{0},", item);
            }
        }

        #endregion // operations

        #region representation

        private readonly Queue<int> _queue;
        private static readonly StreamWriter StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(FILE_PATH);

        #endregion // representation

        #region constants

        private const string FILE_PATH = "data.txt";

        #endregion // constants
    }
}

//Controller.cs

namespace Root
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Timers;

    using MyNamespace.Core;

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides functionality that controls <see cref="Producer"/> and <see cref="Consumer"/> concurency.
    /// </summary>
    public class Controller : IDisposable
    {

        #region construction

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the new instance of <see cref="Controller"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="queue">Shared Queue object.</param>
        public Controller(Queue<int> queue)
        {
            _queue = queue;

            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            _timer.Elapsed += ShowCount;
        }

        #endregion // construction


        #region implementation

        #region Implementation of IDisposable

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the current instance.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (var consumer in _consumers)
            {
                consumer.Dispose();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates consumer/producer objects and ran them each in seperate thread. 
        /// </summary>
        public void Start()
        {
            _consumerThreads = new Thread[_consumerCount];
            _producerThreads = new Thread[_producerCount];
            _consumers = new Consumer[_consumerCount];
            _producers = new Producer[_producerCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < ProducerCount; ++i)
            {
                var producer = new Producer(_queue, _maxSleepInterval);
                _producers[i] = producer;
                _producerThreads[i] = new Thread(() => producer.StartProduce(_source.Token));
                _producerThreads[i].Start();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ConsumerCount; ++i)
            {
                var consumer = new Consumer(_queue, _maxSleepInterval);
                _consumers[i] = consumer;
                _consumerThreads[i] = new Thread(() => consumer.StartConsume(_source.Token));
                _consumerThreads[i].Start();
            }

            _timer.Start();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cancels producing/consuming.
        /// </summary>
        public void Cancel()
        {
            _source.Cancel();
            _timer.Stop();

            for (int i = 0; i < ConsumerCount; ++i)
            {
                _consumerThreads[i].Join();
            }
        }

        #endregion // implementation

        #region properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets consumers count.
        /// </summary>
        public int ConsumerCount
        {
            get { return _consumerCount; }
            set { _consumerCount = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets producers count.
        /// </summary>
        public int ProducerCount
        {
            get { return _producerCount; }
            set { _producerCount = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets maximum sleep interval.
        /// </summary>
        public int MaxSleepInterval
        {
            get { return _maxSleepInterval; }
            set { _maxSleepInterval = value; }
        }

        #endregion // properties

        #region operations

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows the queue size.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Sender object.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event handler argumnets.</param>
        private void ShowCount(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            int count;
            lock (_queue)
            {
                count = _queue.Count;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Items in the queue: {0}", count);
        }

        #endregion // operations

        #region representation

        /// <summary>
        /// Shared between produsers and consumers queue object.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly Queue<int> _queue;

        /// <summary>
        /// Thread in which runs each consumer.
        /// </summary>
        private Thread[] _consumerThreads;

        /// <summary>
        /// Thread in which runs each producer.
        /// </summary>
        private Thread[] _producerThreads;

        /// <summary>
        /// Array of <see cref="Consumer"/> objects.
        /// </summary>
        private Consumer[] _consumers;

        /// <summary>
        /// Array of <see cref="Producer"/> objects.
        /// </summary>
        private Producer[] _producers;

        /// <summary>
        /// Timer object.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Provides cancellation token.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _source = new CancellationTokenSource();

        private int _consumerCount = 10;
        private int _producerCount = 10;
        private int _maxSleepInterval = 100;

        #endregion // representation
    }
}
```

At the end

```
//Program.cs

namespace Root
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int prdCnt;
            int conCnt;

            Console.Write("Enter produsers count[1-10]:");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out prdCnt) || prdCnt < 1 || prdCnt > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                Console.Write("Enter produsers count[1-10]:");
            }

            Console.Write("Enter consumers count[1-10]:");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out conCnt) || conCnt < 1 || conCnt > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                Console.Write("Enter consumers count[1-10]:");
            }

            Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();
            using (var controller = new Controller(queue))
            {
                controller.ConsumerCount = conCnt;
                controller.ProducerCount = prdCnt;
                controller.Start();

                Console.ReadLine();
                controller.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What .NET framework do you use?

Comment: @almaz .net 4.0 , 4.5 but using namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent` not allowed.

Comment: Is any particular reason why specific namespace is not allowed? I can't think of any case when `CancellationToken` would be allowed but not `BlockingCollection`...

Answer (score 2):

The main issue in this code is that several classes rely on each other's proper behaviour in order to work correctly. I'm talking about sharing the instance of `Queue<int>` and requirement for proper locking on it in all places. See remarks to [`lock` Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for recommendations on proper usage.

Since you mentioned that you can't use the `System.Collections.Concurrent` 
namespace I suggest to create a class that mimics BlockingCollection functionality to avoid first issue. It should incapsulate the thread-safe manipulation with queue, so that both `Consumer` and `Producer` don't need to handle multithreading logic.

Also I don't see the reason for deriving `Producer`/`Consumer` from `RandomDataProvider`. They use functionality of `RandomDataProvider`, but not extend it, so classes should not derive from it and rather store the instance of `RandomDataProvider` in a field.